# Emgu CV C# Exception creating tesseract object

Tags: c#-4.0, emgucv

I can access all emgu libraries. VS finds the libraries and `using Emgu.CV.OCR` returns no errors.

When I try to create a `Tesseract` object, Program.cs throws a `FileLoadException`. in `System.Windows.Forms.dll`.

Removing the line of code that creates a tesseract lets the program run fine.

I have tried copying tessdata to my debug file and that also has not worked.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tesseract _ocr;
        _ocr = new Tesseract(@"tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);

        OpenFileDialog Openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (Openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> My_Image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = My_Image.ToBitmap();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I fiddled with the same problem for a while; now I got it.

First, make sure you have the following **using directives** (you might need to download Emgu.CV via NuGet):

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.OCR;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
```

Then, make sure you have the most up-to-date **tessdata** on board. If not, navigate to [github](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata) and download it (click "Clone or Download" and select "Download ZIP File"). You should then unzip the file and rename the folder "tessdata-master" to "tessdata." Copy this folder to the place where your binary lives (the assembly location).

Lastly, assign the **correct path**, and you're ready to do OCR!

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\";  
var _ocr = new Tesseract(path, "eng", OcrEngineMode.Default);
_ocr.SetImage(yourImage);
_ocr.Recognize();
var result = _ocr.GetCharacters();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check your project References . Is there "Emgu.CV.OCR" library if not kindly add it first. Then try the following code may it will work for you.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tesseract _ocr;
       _ocr = new Tesseract(@"C:\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-cuda 2.9.0.1922\Emgu.CV.OCR\tessdata", "eng", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);//first Parameter set your path ..complete path like i did
            _ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopkrstuvwxyz");

        OpenFileDialog Openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (Openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> My_Image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = My_Image.ToBitmap();
        }
    }
```